# Viable T-SQL alternative to a nested IF ELSE for comparisons in which CASE fails

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, case

Is there a viable alternative in T-SQL to a nested IF ELSE for comparisons in which different logic must take place based on the result of the comparison? My situation is involves selecting a nvarchar value representing the condition for evaluation, and based on the condition an evaluation takes place. I initially sought to implement this in a CASE statement as follows:

```
SELECT
            CASE @condition
            WHEN  '<' THEN

                IF (@processing_time < @threshold_value)
                BEGIN
                    SET @condition_met = 1 --compare threshold_value and processing_time
                END

            WHEN '<=' THEN
                    IF (@processing_time <= @threshold_value)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @condition_met = 1 --compare threshold_value and processing_time
                    END
                WHEN '>' THEN
                    IF (@processing_time > @threshold_value)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @condition_met = 1 --compare threshold_value and processing_time
                    END
                WHEN '>=' THEN
                    IF (@processing_time >= @threshold_value)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @condition_met = 1 --compare threshold_value and processing_time
                    END
                WHEN '=' THEN
                    IF (@processing_time = @threshold_value)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @condition_met = 1 --compare threshold_value and processing_time
                    END
            END -- end case statement
```

However, based on what I have seen elsewhere and the syntax errors I am getting, it seems that the WHEN clause in a case statement can only assign values, not perform evaluation logic. The only alternative I can think of is to perform equivalent logic using nested IF/ELSE statements. IS there a better way? Redesign of tables/data types is an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't got a database here to check this syntax hasn't got typos in it but this should do it..

```
set @condition_met = (SELECT 
                        CASE WHEN (@condition = '<' AND @processing_time < @threshold_value) OR
                                  (@condition = '<=' AND @processing_time <= @threshold_value) OR
                                  (@condition = '>' AND @processing_time > @threshold_value) OR
                                  (@condition = '>=' AND @processing_time >= @threshold_value) OR
                                  (@condition = '=' AND @processing_time = @threshold_value) 
                             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Alternatively you could simply do a series of `IF` statements to do the same thing, E.g.

```
SET @condition_met = 0;
IF @condition = "<" AND @processing_time < @threshold_value SET @condition_met = 1;
IF @condition = "<=" AND @processing_time <= @threshold_value SET @condition_met = 1;
etc..
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT @Condition_Met = CASE 
            WHEN (@condition = '<' AND @processing_time < @threshold_value) OR
                 (@condition = '<=' AND @processing_time <= @threshold_value) OR
                 (@condition = '>' AND @processing_time > @threshold_value) OR
                 (@condition = '>=' AND @processing_time >= @threshold_value) OR
                 (@condition = '=' AND @processing_time = @threshold_value) 
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

It seems to me like you're trying to do too much procedural code, and not enough set-based or declarative. I have a feeling this whole thing belongs as part of a larger query such that you  don't even need to declare some of these variables.

Comment: I agree as far as doing too much procedural code. I have only been working with T-SQL for a couple months now, so that is probably part of it.  I believe some of the design has also forced the use of either more advanced use of set based and declarative, or (for me ) more obvious procedural approaches as well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider also dynamic SQL solution.

```
declare @op varchar(5) = '>'
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 
'declare @condition_met bit
declare @processing_time int = 7
declare @threshold_value int = 6

select @condition_met = case when @processing_time'+@op+'@threshold_value then 1 else 0 end
select @condition_met'
exec (@sql)
```

It could be useful, if expression is in the `WHERE` clause and either `@processing_time` or `@threshold_value` is an indexed column and you really want to use index on it.